# Batch processing and error handling in CSV upload in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, rails-activerecord, activeadmin

I am using active admin and uploading the records into the database from CSV file. However, there are two issues occurs here; Code breaks if any filed is missing and secondly performance is very week, can't we do it in the batch process. It is an important and I believe many developers thinking a good solution for such problem.

```
require 'CSV'
class CsvDb
  class << self
    def convert_save(model_name, csv_data, field_name=nil)
      target_model = model_name.classify.constantize
      csv_file = csv_data.read
      row_headers={}
      counter=0;
      #Thread.new do
                CSV.parse(csv_file) do |row| 
                    if counter==0
                        temp=row
                        row_headers = Hash[temp.map.with_index.to_a]
                        counter +=1
                        next
                    end
                    unless row[row_headers["name"]].nil?
                        temp={}
                        business_type = row[row_headers["business_type_id"]]
                        business_type_id = business_type=='Online' ? 1: business_type=='Local' ? 2: 3
                        temp[:business_type_id]         = business_type_id
                        temp[:user_id]                  = row[row_headers["user_id"]]
                        temp[:name]                     = row[row_headers["name"]]
                        temp[:country_id]               = row[row_headers["country_id"]]
                        temp[:homepage]                 = row[row_headers["homepage"]] ||=""
                        temp[:telephone]                = row[row_headers["telephone"]] ||=""
                        temp[:email]                    = row[row_headers["email"]] ||=""
                        temp[:address]                  = row[row_headers["address"]] ||=""
                        temp[:latitude]                 = row[row_headers["latitude"]] 
                        temp[:longitude]                = row[row_headers["longitude"]]
                        temp[:facebook]                 = row[row_headers["facebook"]] ||=""
                        temp[:twitter]                  = row[row_headers["twitter"]] ||=""
                        temp[:google]                   = row[row_headers["google"]] ||=""
                        temp[:instagram]                = row[row_headers["instagram"]] ||=""
                        temp[:pinterest]                = row[row_headers["pinterest"]] ||=""
                        temp[:free_shipping]            = row[row_headers["free_shipping"]]
                        temp[:ship_details]             = row[row_headers["ship_details"]] ||=""
                        temp[:category_ids]             = [row[row_headers["category_ids"]]]
                        temp[:style_ids]                = [row[row_headers["style_ids"]]]
                        temp[:shipping_country_ids]     = [row[row_headers["shipping_country_ids"]]]
                        temp[:filter_ids]               = [row[row_headers["filter_ids"]]]
                        business = target_model.new(temp)
                        business.save
                    end
                end
                ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close
      end
    #end
  end   
end
```

Comment: Any suggestion or trick will be hhighly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll just focus on the translation of the CSV rows into an object. There's just to much repetition in the unless body. All those rows should be mentioned once, then handled in a loop instead of hard coding them like this. E.g.

```
unless row[row_headers["name"]].nil?
    temp={}
    business_type = row[row_headers["business_type_id"]]
    business_type_id = business_type == "Online" ? 1: business_type == "Local" ? 2 : 3
    temp[:business_type_id] = business_type_id
    for name in [:user_id, :name, :country_id, :latitude, :longitude, :free_shipping, :category_ids, :style_ids, :shipping_country_ids]
        temp[name] = row[row_headers[name.to_s]]
    end
    for name in [:homepage, :telephone, :email, :address, :facebook, :twitter, :google, :instagram, :pinterest, :ship_details]
        temp[name] = row[row_headers[name.to_s]] ||= ""
    end
    business = target_model.new(temp)
    business.save
end
```

Alternate solution received from code review site:

```
CSV.parse(csv_file, {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol}) do |row|
  business_type_id =  case row[:business_type_id]
                        when 'Online' then 1
                        when 'Local' then 2
                        else 3
                      end

  target_model.new( {business_type_id: business_type_id} + extract_required_fields(row) + extract_optionals_fiels(row) )
              .save()

end

def extract_required_fields(row)
  [:user_id, :name, :country_id, :free_shipping, :category_ids, :style_ids, :shipping_country_ids]
    .reduce({}) do |carry, item|
      carry[item] = row[item]
  end
end

def extract_optionals_fiels(row)
  [:homepage, :telephone, :email, :address, :facebook, :twitter, :google, :instagram, :pinterest, :ship_details]
    .reduce({}) do |carry, item|
      carry[item] = row[item] ||= ''
  end
end
```